# Python - Infinite loop script running in background + restart

Tags: python, infinite-loop, kill

I would like to have a python script that runs in background (infinite loop).

```
def main():
    # inizialize and start threads
    [...]

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        my.cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    my.cleanup()
```

1. In order to have the application run constantly in infinite loop what is the best way? I want to remove the `time.sleep(1)` which I don't need
2. I would like to run the script in background `nohup python myscript.py &` is there a way to kill it "gracefully"? When I run it normally hitting the CTRL+C `my.cleanup()` is called, is there a way to call this when the kill command is used?
3. What if I would like (using cron) kill the script and restart it again? Is there a way to make it do `my.cleanup()`?

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using Celery? It can run workers in the background on an interval and you can start/stop workers through shell or GUI.

Comment: @nivixzixer celery doesnt do websocket data, I want an infinite loop to listen to websocket data or redis pub channels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. In order to have the application run constantly in infinite loop what is the best way? I want to remove the time.sleep(1) which I don't need

A `while True` or `while <condition>` loop is OK, in my opinion.

A `sleep()` is not mandatory for such a infinite loop as long as you don't require your program to wait for a certain time period.

> 2. I would like to run the script in background nohup python myscript.py & is there a way to kill it "gracefully"? When I run it normally hitting the CTRL+C my.cleanup() is called, is there a way to call this when the kill command is used?

You may want to "listen" to serveral signals using the `signal()` method from the package "`signal`".

Simplified example extended by signal hooks:

```
import time
import signal

# determines if the loop is running
running = True

def cleanup():
  print "Cleaning up ..."

def main():
  global running

  # add a hook for TERM (15) and INT (2)
  signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, _handle_signal)
  signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, _handle_signal)

  # is True by default - will be set False on signal
  while running:
    time.sleep(1)

# when receiving a signal ...
def _handle_signal(signal, frame):
  global running

  # mark the loop stopped
  running = False
  # cleanup
  cleanup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Note, that you can't listen to `SIGKILL`, when terminating a program using that signal, you have no chance to do any clean up. Your program should be aware of that (an do kind of pre-start clean up or fail with a proper message).

Note, I was using a global variable to keep this example simple, I prefer to encapsulate this in a custom class.

> 3. What if I would like (using cron) kill the script and restart it again? Is there a way to make it do my.cleanup()?

As long as your cronjob will kill the program with any signal except `SIGKILL` this is possible, of course.

You should consider doing what you want to do in a different way: for example, if you want to "re-do" some setup task before the infinite loop task, you could also do this upon a certain signal (some programs use `SIGHUP` for reloading configrations, for example). You'd have to break the loop, do the task and resume it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This helped a lot! Two more questions: 1. I don't need the `sleep()` I just need to keep the script alive, what normal developers do? 2. `except KeyboardInterrupt:` is than useless using this: `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, _handle_signal)` right?

Comment: You're right, the `except KeyboardInterrupt` is superflous. I also moved the signal handler registration to `main()`. I'm not sure what you mean with your first question. Don't you need to do any tasks within that loop?

Comment: Thank you, no actually not, I just need the script not to exit